# How to use html-webpack-plugin variable inside <script>?

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to assign variable inside `<script>` tag by means of html-webpack-plugin where the variable is located.
I can easily use it inside html tags like title 
`<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.applicationId %>`

My html-webpack-plugin looks like :

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      applicationId : process.env.APPLICATION_ID ?process.env.APPLICATION_ID : 1,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
```

And I want to use variable ***applicationId*** on index.html page with following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          document.write(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
     var appId = <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.applicationId %>;
   xhr.open("GET","https://somesite.com/NavigationApi/api/content/get?applicationId=" + appId,false);
      xhr.send(null);
    </script>
```

Comment: What is it currently setting `appId` to?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a hidden input and set the `appId` there, then you can retrieve that value with javascript (make sure to do that inside jquery's `onload` event or using [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) if you want to use vanilla JS), hope this helps.